# How to extract value from json in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, c#, json

I am trying to read first value from below json array

```
 var json = "[{\"First\",\"Second\"}]";
```

How do i get value first from above json array.

```
    var result = JObject.Parse(json);
   var result = JArray.Parse(json);
```

I tried above things but both throwing exception.

Comment: Show us the code that you tried...

Comment: What exception? How did you try? And that’s invalid JSON since it’s an array which has one object which should have key-value pairs and it doesn’t.

Comment: And the exception, too. But fundamentally, you're trying to parse it as an object, when it's an array - so use `JArray.Parse`.

Comment: that does not look like valid json. get rid of the { } if all you want is an array with the two string first and second in it: "[\"First\",\"Second\"]"

Comment: So, You want to get only first value from json in javascript code?? Right?

Comment: @praguan in C#..

Comment: The key problem here really is that you try to parse invalid JSON, so your parse function throws an exception.

Answer (score 0):

`Newtonsoft.JSON` is a good solution for this kind of situations. Also Newtonsof.JSON is faster than others such as `JavaScriptSerializer`, `DataContractJsonSerializer`.

In this sample , you can the following :

```
var jsonData = JObject.Parse("your json data here");
```

Then you can cast jsonData to JArray and you can use for loop to get data at each iteration. Also, I want to add something.

Working with dynamic object and using Newtonsoft serialize is a good choice.

Answer (score 0):

```
var json = "[{\"First\",\"Second\"}]";

dynamic result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
```

As you are using jObject It's look like c# code. You can read the json as the given code.

Answer (score 0):

JSON is not a list format, but works like a key value data structure. Try this little Javascript in your **browser console** to understand, how it is supposed to work.

```
obj = JSON.parse("{\"first\":\"First value\", \"second\":\"Second Value, maybe some more text?\"}");
console.log(obj.first);
console.log(obj.second);
```

Prints:

```
First value
Second Value, maybe some more text?
```